# How to replace one character inside parentheses keep everything else as is

Tags: awk, sed, grep

The data looks like this :

```
There is stuff here (word, word number phrases)
(word number anything, word phrases), even more
...
```

There is a lot of them in different files. There is different kind of data too, all around it that isn't in the same format. The data inside the paratheses can't change, and it's always on the same line. I do not have to deal with:

```
(stuff number,
maybe more here)
```

I would like to be able to replace the comma with a colon

Desired output would be

```
There is stuff here (word: word number phrases)
(word number anything: word phrases), even more
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming there's only one comma to be replaced inside parentheses, this [POSIX BRE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html) `sed` expression will replace it with colon:

```
sed 's/(\(.*\),\(.*\))/(\1:\2)/g' file
```

If there are more than one comma, *only the last one* will be replaced.

In multiple-commas scenario, you can replace *only the first one* with:

```
sed 's/(\([^,]*\),\([^)]*\))/(\1:\2)/g' file
```

Comment: the \1 and \2 are they like in `mmv` with #1 and #2? It looks like it.

Comment: `\1` and `\2` hold what's captured with first `(.*)` and second group `(.*)`.

Comment: Because `.*` is greedy, this will only match the **last** comma on a line. It will not work as expected with a line like `foo (bar,baz) qux,blah (hello,fine,world)` -- this will work better: `sed ':a;s/(\([^,)]*\),\([^)]*\))/(\1:\2)/;ta'`

Comment: @glennjackman, that's true. But I'm not sure if OP needs to handle the first comma, the last comma, or all of them..

Comment: @Lorac, any comments?

Comment: If you need sed, `sed 's/(\([^,)]*\),\([^)]*\))/(\1:\2)/g'` would do I think.

Comment: @Lorac, for only the first comma, see the second part of my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a version for awk that uses the parentheses as **record** separators:

```
awk -v RS='[()]' 'NR%2 == 0 {sub(/,/,":")} {printf "%s%s", $0, RT}' file
```

The stuff between parentheses will be every *even-numbered* record. The `RT` variable holds the character that matched the `RS` pattern for this record.

Note that this only replace the first comma of the parenthesized text. If you want to replace all, use `gsub` in place of `sub`

Comment: Note: `RT` is specific to GNU awk

Answer (score 2):

While [@randomir's `sed` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47084094/3832970) dwells on replacing a single comma inside parentheses, there is a way to replace multiple commas inside parentheses with `sed`, too.

Here is the code:

```
sed '/(/ {:a s/\(([^,()]*\),/\1:/; t a}'
```

or

```
sed '{:a;s/\(([^,()]*\),/\1:/;ta}'
```

or

```
sed -E '{:a;s/(\([^,()]*),/\1:/;ta}'
```

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/iVKzGQ).

In all cases, the main part is between the curly braces. Here are the details for the POSIX ERE (`sed` with `-E` option) pattern:

- `:a;`
- `s/(\([^,()]*),/\1:/;` - find and *capture* into Group 1

  - `\(` - a `(` char
  - `[^,()]*` - zero or more chars other than `,`, `(` and `)` (so, only those commas will be removed that are in between the *closest* `(` and `)` chars, not inside `(..,.(...,.)` - remove `(` from the bracket expression to also match in the latter patterns)
  - `\1:` - and replace with the Group 1 contents + a colon after it
- `ta` - loop to `:a` if there was a match at the preceding iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Using **awk**

```
$ awk -v FS="" -v OFS="" '{ c=0; for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){ if( $i=="(" || $i ==")" ) c=1-c; if(c==1 && $i==",") $i=":" } }1' file
There is stuff here (word: word number phrases)
(word number anything: word phrases), even more
```

`-v FS="" -v OFS=""` Set `FS` to null so that each char is treated as a field.

set variable `c=0`.  Iterate over each field using `for` loop and toggle the value of `c` if `(` or `)` is encountered.
if `c==1` and `,` appears then replace it to `:`

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`

```
$ perl -pe 's/\([^()]+\)/$&=~s|,|:|gr/ge' ip.txt
There is stuff here (word: word number phrases)
(word number anything: word phrases), even more

$ echo 'i,j,k (a,b,c) bar (1,2)' | perl -pe 's/\([^()]+\)/$&=~s|,|:|gr/ge'
i,j,k (a:b:c) bar (1:2)

$ # since only single character is changed, can also use tr
$ echo 'i,j,k (a,b,c) bar (1,2)' | perl -pe 's/\([^()]+\)/$&=~tr|,|:|r/ge'
i,j,k (a:b:c) bar (1:2)
```

- `e` modified allows to use Perl code in replacement section
- `\([^()]+\)` match non-nested `()` with one or more characters inside
- `$&=~s|,|:|gr` perform another substitution on matched text, the `r` modifier would return the modified text