# Character replacement inside multiple matched pattern

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

Let's say I have a sentence like this

```
The quick, (brown, fox) jumps over, the (lazy, old, dog)
```

I want to replace all the commas `,` inside parentheses `()` to colons `:`, however commas that are not enclosed by parentheses should not be replaced. The output should be like

```
The quick, (brown: fox) jumps over, the (lazy: old: dog)
```

Notice that the number of commas and parentheses are not fixed in each sentence.
How can use shell related tools (bash, sed, awk etc.) to achieve this result?

I have tried to use `sed 's/[^(]*\(([^)]*)\)/\1/g; s/,/:/g'` to make substitution to all matched groups, but not sure how to plug the results back to the original sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your actual Input_file is same as shown Input then following may help you in same.

```
awk -F"[)(]" '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2){gsub(/,/,":",$i);$i="("$i")"}} 1'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
The quick,  (brown: fox)  jumps over, the  (lazy: old: dog)
```

Comment: Nice idea on using loop with step 2 increment! However it seems that some additional spaces are generated, is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: Solved it with `OFS=""`, thanks!

Comment: @etopylight Are you sure it works as expected? Try with [`, even more :) with smilies`](https://ideone.com/2niHXA) added to the test string. [This is the correct `awk` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47084209/3832970) (just change `sub` to `gsub`).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Good catch! That's a more robust solution which handles unclosed parentheses nicely.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thanks for letting know.

Comment: I also have a sed solution, but I will most probably post it in the original thread.